# Symfony 1.4 sfguard plugin related tables

Tags: symfony-1.4, propel, sfguard

I am developing project with symfony 1.4 using sfguard plugin and propel orm. I have some tables related to **sf_guard_user** table. I have to show these tables all together on admin interface. But sfguard plugin only allow adding one table which is named as sfuserprofile. When I created this table, I can reach the columns of this tables from generator.yml.

But I have to add so many data to database which is related to user such as location, detailed address, tel numbers and of course all of associated tables. I can not store all of them on sfuserprofile table. I have create some tables such as user_profile, user_address_details, user_album_images etc. But I could not integrate all of these tables except user_profile table to generator file.

I have red the read me file but I could not find any clues. Is it possible adding another table column to sfguard generator file.

**Edit:**

The solution is merging the target form classes in userprofile form class.

Comment: if you are talking about displaying those fields in your form, maybe a better solution would be paying with `embedForm` cause it will do the automatic saving for you)

Answer (score 1):

Either use partials (fields defined with `_` in front of them) or define getters in you sfGuardUser model for each field you want to display. More information http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/14-Generators (look for `Custom Fields` and `Partial Fields`).

That is a symfony 1.2 documentation. Some of the things are different in symfony 1.4, but it's enough info there to get you going on the right track.